# Issues connecting to Microsoft Exchange online using PowerShell - app only authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, exchange-server, azure-ad-msal, o365-flow

I could not connect to Exchange Online, I get the below error while connecting

**Error Acquiring Token:**
System.Exception: *In the case of a Federated user(that is owned by a federated IdP, as opposed to a managed user owned in an Azure AD tenant)*
ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.The user does not exist or has entered the wrong pas
swordInnerException : Federated service

**PowerShell Code**

```
$AppCredential= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(<UPN>,<Token>)

Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $AppCredential
```

*Reference*

https://o365reports.com/2020/07/04/modern-auth-and-unattended-scripts-in-exchange-online-powershell-v2/

Answer (score 0):

Connect to Exchange Online using **App-only authentication** Feature is not available in **EXO V2**.

**Delegation is not possible with app-only authentication. The Secure App Model allows for unattended scripting in delegation scenarios.**

Delegation is not supported in this Feature.

> Note: **Decrease your EXO V2 into V1 then you can use the same scripts to connect the Exchange Online using APP-only Authentication.**. But This way is not recommended.

Refer [here](https://www.microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/Secure-Application-Model/Unsure-how-to-use-app-only-authentication-in-the-EXO-V2-module/m-p/23286)

Comment: Thank you for your information, It's possible only, please refer this  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps) ,